# Finding Distance Function via integration

Tags: integration

I would just like to confirm if:

```
- If my answer is correct
- Or find the source of my mistake.
```

[image]

My answer: $-t^2e^{-t} -2te^{-t} -2e^{-t}$

Apologies for the terrible formatting of mathematical statements, I don't know how to input mathematical formulas into text.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take into account the constant of integration?

If you don't want to explicitly worry about the constant, just integrate between the bounds 0 and t.

You'll find there's a "+2" missing at the end of your expression.

Comment: Just to clarify, will integrating between 0 and the variable (which in this case is t) always give me the "constant of integration"?

Comment: No, the point is that you don't have to worry about a constant of integration in a definite integral. The question asks you to find the distance travelled from time 0 to time t. This is why those bounds are appropriate. BTW, one extra subtlety that you may or may not have noticed: the v(t) function is always non-negative, which means the particle is always going in one direction. Hence the distance is identical to the displacement. However, if v(t) becomes negative anywhere then that will complicate the analysis. This doesn't happen here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the distance is negative everywhere while the velocity is positive. The correct formula is

$$s(t)-s(0)=\int_0^t x^2e^{-x}dx=-(t^2+2t+2)e^{-t}+2.$$

If you assume that $s(0)=0$ (since the question is: how far will it travel?) then you have

$$s(t)=2-(t^2+2t+2)e^{-t}.$$

PS: To write the first mathematical expression write

\$ s(t)-s(0)=\int_0^t x^2e^{-x}dx=-(t^2+2t+2)e^{-t}+2 \$

Comment: The question does not state what $ s(0) $ is, so should I assume that in this case $ s(0) = 2 $ ... I mean, according to what I have read in all the answers, it would seem that to fine the missing "+2" I would need to know that $ s(0) = 2 $ right?

Comment: Actually the missing $+2$ is to have $s(0)=0.$ Note that $f(t)=-(t^2+2t+2)e^{-t}$ satisfies $f(0)=-2.$

Answer (score 0):

If $F(t)$ is an antiderivative of $t^2e^{-t}$, then the change in displacement  is $F(t)-F(0)$. The $F(0)$ part is missing.

**Remark:** If we were integrating say $3t^2+2$, we would get $t^3+2t$, which is $0$ at $0$. But not all functions vanish at $0$! This is a common source of (minor) error.